calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}} |\langle a_i,x\rangle |^2e^{-||Ax||_2^2/2}dx$
I'm reading probabilistic method about gaussian distribution.I'm not familiar with high dimensional intergral and can not calculate it.How to calculate it?
Here $a_i,x\in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $\langle,\rangle$ means inner product.$A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix with each row $a_i$

What is $a_i$? Is that a sum over $i$ missing somewhere? Is $a_i$ the $i$th column of the matrix $A$?

$a_i$ is the transpose of the $i$-th row of $A$

do you know what is the answer if $n = m = 1$?
